# On Android, how to avoid user navigation between my app and another launched by Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to display pdf in Android. To do so I launch an installed pdf application thanks to an Intent with ACTION_VIEW. 
Let's consider that there is no popup asking the user to select its favorite pdf application (my Intent targets an explicit pdf reader).
Of course this works but there are 2 processes on the device, my app and the pdf reader. As a consequence the user can switch between this 2 apps (it is possible to come back to my app without closing the pdf reader app). Is there any mean to avoid this behavior ? For example, this is not observed when the camera is launched (using the intent filter android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE).

Comment: why do you need to prevent that behavior ? what is the problem with it ?

Comment: can you post the code you are using for intent launch